# Aggregate document value per hour

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question about aggregation. I read about [Date Histogram Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation). But it only sorts documents by date. So I have index **visits** with field **date** and **visited_page**. And I want to aggregate for example counts per hour(e.g. user visiting page per hour). Will aggregation above should be used or I should somehow aggregate in different way?

Comment: what is visited_page type? integer? string? could you give example of data, please?

Comment: let it be string. I just need count per each visited_page hourly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is supposed to be like this below:

```
GET {index_name}/{type}/_search
{
  "size": 0, // no need to display search result, can boost query speed
  "aggs": {
    "unique_visited_page": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "visited_page" // this must be indexed with keyword type
      },
      "aggs": {
        "visit_page_per_hour" : {
          "date_histogram" : {
              "field" : "date_field",
              "interval" : "hour"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We aggregate by **visited_page** first then per each **visited_page**, we drill down it per hour to get the count.

Example response using my sample data

```
{
  ...
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "unique_visited_page": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "contact.html",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "visit_page_per_hour": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key_as_string": "2018-07-24T14:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1532440800000,
                "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                "key_as_string": "2018-07-24T15:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1532444400000,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "index.html",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "visit_page_per_hour": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key_as_string": "2018-07-24T13:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1532437200000,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "page.html",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "visit_page_per_hour": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key_as_string": "2018-07-24T13:00:00.000Z",
                "key": 1532437200000,
                "doc_count": 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The key of the result is our **visited_page** value then it will be aggregated per hour and return the **doc_count**. The **doc_count** perhaps the value that you want.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Finally managed to check your answer. Had few problems but resolved them. That's exactly what I've needed. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need multi-bucket aggregation.
I found [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html)

What you are interested in is this:

```
 GET /_search
{
    "aggs" : {
        "my_buckets": {
            "composite" : {
                "sources" : [
                    { "date": { "date_histogram": { "field": "timestamp", "interval": "1d" } } },
                    { "product": { "terms": {"field": "product" } } }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> This will create composite buckets from the values created by two values source, a date_histogram and a terms. Each bucket is composed of two values, one for each value source defined in the aggregation. Any type of combinations is allowed and the order in the array is preserved in the composite buckets.

Does it help?

Comment: I have an exception with your example. Should I add some metadata to index for these kind of aggregations?

SearchParseException[Could not find aggregator type [composite] in [my_buckets]];

Comment: @Shioshin which version of ES are you using? As you may see in the documentetion this type of aggregation is _in beta_ state and it looks like it was introduced first in 6.1